# Traduction de « to make sense »

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions, choix-de-mot, oral

Dans les discussions que j'ai déjà eues, « It makes sense. » exprime à la fois le fait que l'interlocuteur comprend et que *cela* veut effectivement dire quelque chose. De même « It does not make sense » veut plutôt dire « Cela n'a pas de sens ».

Mon problème, c'est que traduire « make sense » par « être sensé » ou « avoir du sens » semble correct mais me semble trop artificiel, littéral et forcé.

Par exemple « this definition makes sense » traduit en « cette définition est sensée » ou « a du sens » me semble une perte de naturel. Existe-t'il une meilleure alternative utilisable facilement, notamment à l'oral ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dans le registre familier, il y a

> Cela tient la route.

On dirait plutôt

> Cela a *un* sens.

que « cela a *du* sens ».

> Cela est sensé.

convient aussi.

Enfin, des traductions moins litérales sont possibles, par exemple :

> C'est logique.

Comment: +1 pour _C'est logique_, qui semble le plus naturel. Personnellement, c'est la traduction que j'utilise.

Comment: @Stamm: Ben moi qui fais de la logique formelle, bien des fois, je préfère que les gens s'abstiennent… J'ai donné +1 pour les autres, et parce que c'est vrai que le dernier est souvent employé (à mon grand dam).

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez L'expression est ici à prendre au sens « grand public » et non, je pense, au sens mathématique. Mais, pour un logicien, ça ne doit pas être facile tous les jours. Je compatis. :-)

Answer (score 3):

- Ça se tient.
- Ça tient debout.

Answer (score 3):

J'ajouterais :

> C'est raisonnable

A mi-chemin entre le bon sens et la logique, peut-être :)

Answer (score 3):

Dans les milieux religieux / responsables / authentico-durables j'entends souvent l'expression *faire sens* - traduction directe.

Par ex : *Consommer responsable fait sens*.

L'apparition de cette expression dans une conversation me fait en général penser qu'il vaut mieux que je m'en aille, mais elle me parait correspondre à ce que vous cherchez, et je ne pense pas qu'elle soit fautive du strict point de vue de la langue ?

[faire sens](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faire_sens) sur le wiktionnaire, et [ici](http://www.etudes-litteraires.com/forum/topic32045-faire-sens.html) une critique de cette expression.

Comment: En effet j'ai très envie d'utiliser _faire sens_ car je sais que mon interlocuteur comprendra souvent que je veux dire _make sense_ (pas grâce au sens original mais parce qu'il parle anglais) mais c'est tellement laid et bizarre que d'habitude la conversation se focalise dessus.

Comment: Oh ? Moi je trouve ça très sensé et joli, comme expression, au contraire… (plus synthétique qu'*avoir du sens*, notamment) (à noter que la critique semble plus attaquer le nettement moins joli *faire **du** sens*)

Comment: Si je n'aime pas beaucoup cette expression, c'est surtout parce que elle est devenue une sorte de ritournelle, destinée à occuper l'espace de la parole, sans rapport avec quoi que ce soit. Un peu comme _Parlons concrètement_, etc. Ce n'est pas à cause de l'expression elle même.

Answer (score 3):

Pour la négative « It does not make sense » :

> Ça ne veut rien dire.